# jqplot not appearing if data is passed as a paramener via function

Tags: javascript, php, json, jqplot

I am trying to display a [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/axisLabelsRotatedText.html) and the data required to create the chart is being passed via function parameter like `function updatetestGraph(graphData)`
if i do the `console.log(graphData)` I see the following JSON

`[['07/9/2014',500],['07/8/2014',900],['07/7/2014',1200],['07/6/2014',500],['07/5/2014',500],['07/4/2014',500],['07/11/2014',3000]]`

The problem is if I assign `graphData` to another JS variable or use `graphData` directly to display graph it does not work, but if I copy the JSON from console log the graphs appears just fine. I dont understand what is the problem both JSON are the same and have the same format.

The error i get if I use `graphData` or assign it to another variable is `Error: No data specified`

Following is my JS function that I am using to display graph

```
function updatetestGraph(graphData) {
    $('#how_long').empty();
    var newHolidaysData;
    newHolidaysData = graphData;
    console.log(newHolidaysData);
    how_long_plot = $.jqplot('how_long', [newHolidaysData], {
        seriesColors: [ "#F2A809"],
        series: [
            {
                lineWidth: 5,
                markerOptions: { style: 'circle' }
            }
        ],
        grid: {
            background: 'transparent',
            borderColor: '#ffffff',
            borderWidth: 2.0
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                tickInterval: '1 day',
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                shadowAlpha: '0.1',
                tickOptions: {
                    angle: 15,
                    showGridline: false,
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    formatString: '%b %#d'
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max:<?php echo $factfinddata->getFactFind('holiday_goal_target'); ?>,
                label: '',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    showGridline: false,
                    prefix: '$'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //end of script for how long will it take me chart
}
```

I will really appreciate any assistance here, please do not ask me to create fiddle as i have yet to explore how fiddle works and I am frustrated enough with this trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/HAa9p/) is a jsfiddle for your issue.

I have added a min value for the xaxis in order to be able to draw the graph. If you comment line 24 :

```
min: '07/1/2014'
```

the graph isn't rendered.

The other solution is to remove the tickInterval option in order to draw the graph.

Maybe your issue can be related to something like that? Please keep me posted.

Comment: i ended up re coding the entire ajax call to fix the problem and it is working fine now. The problem was not that graph was not appearing, it was appearing the first time user visits the page but once he makes some changes to the data graph was supposed to get updated as well and here the update function was not working the way it was supposed to for some reason. I ended up using .replot to fix the problem. (http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core- js.html#jqPlot.replot) Once again thank you so much for your time.